# How do I initialize Cloud Firestore in php?

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, grpc, google-api-php-client

I followed these tutorials to use Firestore in PHP :
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

but when I load my page, this message is displayed :

> Google\ApiCore\ValidationException: Error rendering 'projects/{project=*}/databases/{database=*}': expected binding 'project' to match segment '{project=*}', instead got null Provided bindings: Array ( [project] => [database] => (default) ) in C:\wamp64\www\php\vendor\google\gax\src\ResourceTemplate\RelativeResourceTemplate.php on line 238'

This is my code :

composer.json :

```
 {
    "require": {
        "google/cloud-firestore": "^1.4",
        "grpc/grpc": "v1.19.0"
    }
}
```

index.php (copy of exemple):

````
require ('vendor/autoload.php');
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

/**
 * Initialize Cloud Firestore with default project ID.
 * ```
 * initialize();
 * ```
 */
    // Create the Cloud Firestore client
    $db = new FirestoreClient();
    printf('Created Cloud Firestore client with default project ID.' . 
PHP_EOL);



$docRef = $db->collection('users')->document('lovelace');
$docRef->set([
    'first' => 'Ada',
    'last' => 'Lovelace',
    'born' => 1815
]);
````

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a default project ID set.

Try setting the `GCLOUD_PROJECT` environment variable to your project ID.

```
set GCLOUD_PROJECT=PROJECT_ID
```

You can also try setting the project ID like this:

```
$db = new FirestoreClient([
        'projectId' => 'my-project-id',
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping fellow Firestore developer Juan!

Comment: Thank you but, I tried to set my environment variable in powershell with : `" [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("GCLOUD_PROJECT", "ProjetID")"` but this doesn't change anything. More, when I reload my computer, this line disappears in `"Get-ChildItem Env:"`

Comment: Added another suggestion, try setting the project ID in your code. If this works, then you can figure out how to make sure `GCLOUD_PROJECT` is in your env.